# python: copy common base class variables

Tags: python

Is there a way to copy (or create and copy like copy.copy()) only the base class variables of two classes that inherit from that same base class?

The purpose is to avoid the future need to implement a method that does the copy and modify it every time adding/removing a variable from the base class.

```
import copy

class Base:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.common_var=val

class SubclassA(Base):
    def __init__(self, val, base_val):
        super(SubclassA, self).__init__(base_val)
        self.var_a=0

class SubclassB(Base):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.var_b=0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_1 = A(1, 2)
    a_2 = copy.copy(a_1)   # Example coping all variables

    b_1 = SubclassB(3)
    # Now, how to copy to a_1 base class variables to variable of the type SubclassB?
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines like: `a_2 = copy.copy(a_1)` will do a normal shallow copy. Instances at runtime are considered 'flat', that is, an instance is like a dictionary where the keys are the names of the variables, and inheritance is like merging dictionaries together.

So then, `a_2` will now reference a *new instance* of `SubclassA`.

*Note:*

```
class SubclassB(Base):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__(val)
        self.var_b = 0

b_1 = SubclassB(a_1)  # note the parameter is a_1
b_2 = copy.copy(b_1)
```

Both `b_1` and `b_2` with reference the *same* instance of `SubclassA`. You may want to use `deepcopy` to produce all new instances.